# Initializing a string with a single character

Tags: c++, string, initialization, character

I want to initialize a `std::string` with a single character. The following code doesn't work:

```cpp
int main()
{
    string s = 'c';
    cout<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
error: conversion from ‘char’ to non-scalar type ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ requested
  string s = 'c';
```

But the following does work. Why is it so?

```cpp
int main()
{
    string s;
    s = 'c';
    cout<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
c[Finished in 0.8s]
```

Comment: `string s = "c"` works!

Comment: [the constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) don't have one that accept one character while [`operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) have one. I don't know why.

Comment: @NathanOliver The target is wrong. OP is not asking for a fix, but why assignment works and not initialization. I'm reopening.

Comment: `string s = 'c';` --> `string s(1, 'c');`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do

```
string s = 'c';
```

you are basically invoking constructor initialisation rather than an assignment operation. But there isn’t any constructor for `std::string` that takes only a single `char` as input. There is however one `std::string(n, c)`, where `n` is the number of characters `c` in the string.

When you do

```
s = 'c'
```

you do an assignment operation, invoking the overloaded `string::operator=` (`string& operator= (char c);`) for `std::string`. Now this method is overloaded to accept a single `char` as input as well, as you can see from the code snippet at this [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) as well as at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/) one.

```
std::string str1;
// ...
// (4) operator=( CharT );
str1 = '!';
```

Additionally, [`std::string::assign`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/assign/) doesn’t accept a single `char`, similar to the constructor.

Comment: It might be nice to add why `std::string s{'c'};` does indeed work.